# Force Blazor WebAssembly app to open an Edge window from IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, blazor-webassembly

I am fiddling with Blazor WebAssembly to make a PoC and try to convince some people to start using it to develop Intranet web apps. However, our standard browser for Intranet content is IE11. Since Blazor WebAssembly is not supported in IE11, it may as well be the best thing in the world but I believe we will not get off to a good start by saying "This does not run in IE11, so people must use Edge for this particular app".

In order to minimize this issue, I was wondering how to make some URLs open on Edge. I know this is possible because if I paste a Teams meeting URL onto IE11, the page is not rendered and a new Edge window opens up automatically instead. Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it seems that you want to open an Edge window from IE 11 browser and view the website, right?

In this scenario, I think you could try to use the URL Scheme: `microsoft-edge:{website url}`. Then, it could open the Edge browser from IE 11 browser.

Sample code as below:

```
  <a href="microsoft-edge:https://www.google.com">link</a>
```

[Note] If you are viewing the website on IOS , the URL scheme should like this: `microsoft-edge-http://` or `microsoft-edge-https://`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Not exactly.. What happens now is that when I paste a normal HTTPS url for a Teams meeting, IE11 does not open the link and an Edge window automatically opens. I don't know how that is accomplished because the URL is perfectly normal.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use IE11 browser to join a Microsoft Teams meeting, but it will auto open an Edge browser to open this link? I have checked it on my side, the result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsLtw.png), since IE11 browser doesn't fully support Microsoft Teams meetings, for the best meeting experience, it suggests to use the Teams app or join in Microsoft Edge. Please check your code, perhaps you clicked the "Join in Microsoft Edge" button.

Comment: Nevermind.. I just talked with the people responsible for the group policies and they confirmed that there are some policies in place to open some websites directly on Edge. Thank you for your time.